# Jquery form submit variable undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying to run some jquery code before submitting form so when user hits submit function a function is executed where i send a post request to server to check if user already exist. in post request response is coming but in my code it always says undefined

**This is my code on submit**

```
      $('#addmember').submit(function() {
        phone = $('#phone').val();
        password = $('#password').val();
        password_confirmation = $('#password_confirmation').val();
        if (phone.length != 10) {
            alert('Please enter a valid mobile number');
            return false;
        }
        if (password.length < 6) {
            alert('Minimum password length is 6');
            return false;
        }
        if (password != password_confirmation) {
            alert('Confirm password is not matching');
            return false;
        }

        check = checkExist(phone);


        if(check != 0 ) {

            alert('Mobile Number is already registered please use some other number!');
            return false;
        }


    });


function checkExist(phone) {
     $.post("{{url('user/check')}}", {
            "_token": $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
            phone: phone
        },
        function(data, status) {

           return data;

        });

}
```

when i run this `check` variable is always undefined

Comment: Where's the `check` the function?

Comment: above jquery code is complete

Comment: Ah, it's asynchronous.

Comment: Look at the dupe question. The `$.post()` is asynchronous. You can return values this way.

Comment: Regarding your "complete jQuery" code, I mentioned for `"{{url('user/check')}}"` - This is not a part of JS. That's why, but that doesn't matter in this context.

Comment: i still did't get what i need to change in my code

Comment: do i need to use set-timeout function ?

Comment: You need to copy the whole stuff inside your `function(data, status) {

           return data;

        });`

Comment: **Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176872/discussion-between-praveen-kumar-purushothaman-and-sunil-meena).**

Comment: Okay, good luck solving yourself. Bye.